# c split string in 2 and print initial result

Tags: c

I'm doing a Linux shell small emulator; everything works fine except when I want to send a command with arguments.

I have used `strtok` to achieve this but the problem is when I'm try to concatenate the `command` with the `args`. When I add an empty space on the command string, the `args` string will be empty. I'm not sure if maybe I'm just doing something wrong with the pointers but I haven't used C for a while.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define commandSize 100

/* Obtem o comando da string e remove \n */
char *getCommandFormatted(char input[])
{
    char *newline = strchr(input, '\n'); 
    if(newline) *newline = 0;
    return strtok(input, " ");    
}

/* Imprime na consola os comandos disponiveis ao utilizador */
void printAvailableCommands(char availableCommands[5][10])
{
    printf("Comandos disponiveis: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++) printf("[%s] ", availableCommands[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

/* Verifica se o comando inserido existe na aplicacao */
int commandExists(char *formattedCommand, char availableCommands[5][10])
{
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++) if(strcmp(formattedCommand ,availableCommands[i]) == 0) found = 1;  
    return found;
}

int main ()
{
    int message = 0;
    char input[1024];
    char output[1024];
    char *command, *args;    
    char availableCommands[5][10] = 
    {
        "who",
        "list",
        "processes",
        "help",
        "exit"
    };

    printf("Introduza um dos seguintes comandos: [who] [list] [processes] [help] [exit]\n");

    do
    {        
        printf("$ ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

        char *newline = strchr(input, '\n'); 
        if(newline) *newline = 0;
        command = strtok(input, " "); // first string
        args = strtok(NULL, ""); // second string
        message = 0;

        // Mapeamento dos comandos da aplicacao com os da shell do linux
        if(strcmp(command ,availableCommands[1]) == 0) command = "ls";
        else if(strcmp(command ,availableCommands[2]) == 0) command = "top";    
        else if(strcmp(command ,availableCommands[3]) == 0) message = 1;
        else if(commandExists(command, availableCommands) == 0) message = 2;

             


        // Envia para a shell apenas os comandos do linux
        if(message == 1) printAvailableCommands(availableCommands);            
        else if(message == 2) printf("Comando %s inválido. Introduza o comando help para obter ajuda.\n", command);
        else {
            if(args != 0 ){ 
                strcat(command, " ");
                strcat(command, args);
                strcpy(output, command);
                system(output); 
            }   
            else system(command); 
        }
    }
    while(strcmp(input, "exit") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is crying out for a loop and a simple look-up table.

Comment: @tadman You mean i should use a loop to check the content of the string instead splitting ?

Comment: I'm talking specifically about that `if`/`else if` chain that could be reduced and made more generic if there's a pattern there. Normally when writing a command interpreter you'd have a `NULL`-terminated array of some kind of structure that defines each command, then you spin through it to test for matches.

Comment: @tadman I see, i didn't mention this is just an assignment with some requirements and I don't want to spend time making it look more maintainable cause there's no need for it. My issue at hand is separating the command and args and send it all together at the end

Comment: There's a fine line between "look maintainable" and "learn how to do it properly", but sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```c
    if(strcmp(command ,availableCommands[1]) == 0) command = "ls";
```

you are assigning the address of a constant string literal to `command`. Then, when you later do something like the following:

```c
        strcat(command, args);
```

you are attempting to modify that *constant* string by appending `args` to it. This causes undefined behaviour.

Instead, in place of the first line shown, you should be copying the data from the literal into the `command` variable:

```c
    if(strcmp(command ,availableCommands[1]) == 0) strcpy(command, "ls");
```

And similarly in other cases.

---

EDIT: Further, the value of `args` returned by `strtok` will point to memory that is 'overlapped' by that pointed to by `command`, so your later `strcat(command, " ");` line will likely write the `NUL` terminator (following the appended space) into the first character of `args`, thus making that an empty string. You should make `args` a *copy* of that memory, using `strdup`:

```c
    args = strdup(strtok(NULL, "")); // second string
```

And don't forget to free that copy at the end of the loop:

```c
        //...
        free(args); // Release the copied memory
    } while (strcmp(input, "exit") != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although this is not the main problem because i have been testing with the command "who" only. When I type "who -a", when i add a whitespace to the command variable, the args variable will lose "-a". Can't see why

Comment: @Jackal See edit - the strings pointed to by `command` and `args` after the `strtok` calls will overlap.

Comment: thanks, i had a feeling it was something with pointers incrementing on each other but didn't know where was this happening. It's working perfectly now